# Как получить разницу во времени в формате hh:mm в Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Хочу получить разницу во времени в часах и минутах. В формате вида `hh:mm`. Есть ли для этого какая то стандартная функция или что-то такое?
Пока наколхозил такое решение, но оно кажется слишком костыльным:

```
with src as (
  select sysdate as finishmoment,
  to_date('29.02.2016') as activationmoment
  from dual
)
select  
  trunc((finishmoment-activationmoment)*24)||' :'||to_char(trunc(mod((finishmoment-activationmoment)*24, 1)*60), '00') as runtime
from src
```

Кто знает решение получше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, остается только **такой вариант** (аналогичный с вашим):

```
select round((sysdate - to_date('29.02.2016')) * 24) || ':' || 
       round(mod((sysdate - to_date('29.02.2016'))*24*60, 60))
from dual
```

---

Вот [тут](http://www.sql.ru/forum/839749/raznica-minuty-i-sekundy-dvuh-dat) еще указали такой вариант с использованием `NUMTODSINTERVAL`, то есть для вашего варианта **будет так**:

```
select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL((sysdate - to_date('29.02.2016'))*24,'HOUR')) +
       24*trunc(sysdate - to_date('29.02.2016')) || ' : ' ||
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL((sysdate - to_date('29.02.2016'))*1440,'MINUTE'))
from dual
```

По коду, в принципе, равноценно (хотя 1-й вариант имхо покороче, можно все вынести в отдельную функцию, например), выбирать вам.

Answer (score 5):

Если учесть, что разница не может быть более 24 часа, то можно так:

```
with src as (
  select 
      to_date('29.02.2016 23:59') as finishmoment,
      to_date('29.02.2016') as activationmoment
  from dual
)
select  
     regexp_substr(
         (finishmoment-activationmoment) day(6) to second, '\d{2}:\d{2}') as runtime
from src;    
--23:59
```

С учётом комментария - если разница в часах может быть более 24 часа, то:

```
with src as (
    select 
        (sysdate - to_date('2016-02-26')) day(4) to second as intrv
    from dual
) 
select 
    extract(day from intrv) * 24 + 
    extract(hour from intrv) || ':' || 
    lpad(extract(minute from intrv), 2, 0) as runtime
from src;
```

Comment: Например так `72:13` что символизирует 72 часа, 13 минут

Comment: Ааа! а если боле 99 часов, то 172:13?  Попробую, но думаю extract, как и советует oracle, будет самое уместное решение.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

---

```html
with src as (
  select sysdate as finishmoment,
  to_date('29.02.2016','dd.mm.yyyy') as activationmoment
  from dual
)
select d*24+h||':'||lpad(mi,2,'0')
  from (
select EXTRACT(DAY FROM (finishmoment-activationmoment) DAY TO SECOND) d,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (finishmoment-activationmoment) DAY TO SECOND) h,
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (finishmoment-activationmoment) DAY TO SECOND) mi
  from src)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант вместо математики использовать функцию [NUMTODSINTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)

Или же попробовать полученный интервал добавить к любой дате с временем 00:00:00 и от полученной даты уже взять только часы и минуты, отформатировав ее как хочется. Решение имеет один минус - может появится трудноуловимая ошибка, когда интервал станет больше суток.

Comment: Ситуация, когда время больше суток может возникать достаточно часто.

Comment: Тогда только математика. А вообще вопрос довольно часто встречается на англоязычном SO - там вариантов побольше будет.

Answer (score 1):

Метод c **NUMTODSINTERVAL**:

-000000010 00:00:12.000000000 превращаем в -10 00:00:12
(не для промышленного применения)

```
regexp_replace(numtodsinterval(s.PREV_EXEC_START - s.LOGON_TIME, 'DAY'),
  '^([[\+\-])(0+)([[0-9]*) ([[0-9]+:[[0-9]+:[[0-9]+)(.0+)$','\1\3 \4') as ss_time 
  -- -000000010 00:00:12.000000000 превращаем в -10 00:00:12
```