# Нужно вычислить время которое понадобилась для доставки

Tags: sql, oracle

Привет всем можете подсказать как вычислить за какое время достался клиенту ?
Имея следующую информацию

```
----------------------------------------------- 
data_zakaza  |           data_poluchen    |  
15/03/2017                 16/03/2017
17/03/2017                 19/03/2018
3/16/2017 12:59          3/16/2017 14:59
```

тип данных `date` у обоих
результат должен быть data_poluchen - data_zaka = время затраченное на доствку

Comment: И каким именно должен быть результат для приведенных данных? Еще желательно указать, какой тип имеют эти столбцы в базе.

Comment: Добавил информации.

Comment: @СмокБелью Вы так и не ответили, какой результат вы хотите увидеть. Месяцы, недели, дни, часы, минуты. Самый тривиальный способ выглядит как `select data_poluchen-data_zakaza from table` и не понятно, чем он Вам не подходит.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498722/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-hhmm-%D0%B2-oracle